# AttributeError when training CNN 1D with Python Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, progress-bar, conv-neural-network

I have tried to build a CNN 1D but the interpreter says me:

> AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'

Here is the code snippet:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(200, 20, activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(1154,1024))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(X, y,batch_size=10, epochs=25,validation_split=0.7)
```

and this is the error:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 1154, 200)         4096200   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,096,200
Trainable params: 4,096,200
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None

Train on 0 samples, validate on 1 samples
Epoch 1/25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_classification.py", line 59, in <module>
    history=model.fit(X, y,batch_size=10, epochs=25,validation_split=0.7)
  File "/home/isabella/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/isabella/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py",
line 217, in fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/home/isabella/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py",
line 79, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/home/isabella/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py",
line 338, in on_epoch_end
    self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values)
AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'

X shape is :(1,1154,1024),
y shape is :(1,1154, 1 )
```

Comment: Which version is this? `pip install --upgrade keras` to ensure you are on the latest version.

Comment: Done, so I am currently using the last version of Keras. The error is still there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look carefully you will see this line right before stack trace output:

```
Train on 0 samples, validate on 1 samples
```

There is no training data! Why? That's because you have set the `validation_split` to `0.7` so at first 70% of the data points in `X` (and `y`) are put aside for validation and the remaining 30% is used for training. Probably the number of data points in `X` is less than 4 and therefore its 30% would amount to less than 1 which means zero data points remains for training. Either use more than 4 data points or remove the `validation_split` argument (or lower it such that at least one sample remains for training).

Comment: thank you so much, i did not see it. but it is so strange because i have 1154 samples, not 1.

Comment: @isabella I don't think so. After the stack trace you can see this: `X shape is :(1,1154,1024),` that means you have **one sample** of shape `(1154, 1024)` (i.e. 1154 timesteps of length 1024 as one sample).